# Sharing Data bwtween different AppDomain

Tags: appdomain

I'm trying to sending data from newDomain to cureentDomain.
I used DoCallBack for loading list of .dll and extract file&assembly information as Dictionary type.
And tried to send key/value data to currentDomain.

It's my first time to use appDomain, so I just found rough way, Set/GetData.
For using that, too much converting process needed, and it shows it can make exceptions in a variety of situations.

If I can send Dictionary, it will be very excellent way of that.
Please, let me know~

Comment: could you please post some code? and if exceptions are troubling you could you please post those (and their stacktrace) too?

Comment: Setdata do share data between appDomains as object type, so if I just do SetData Dictionary<string, string> with mark, then casting object to previous type is enought to solve that.